# Diseño de botón en pie de pantalla

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

Necesito agregar un diseño y posición de botón muy particular.

[image: Pie de pagina y boton]

Pero al agregar constraints me salen errores, no estoy seguro de cómo se deberían agregar dichos constraint, lo estoy haciendo desde xcode sin usar código.
Me podrían ayudar en cómo debería agregar los constraints ?

- Es un Botón y un UIView, el botón esta encima del UIView, puse un view por comodidad pero podría poner imagen o algún componente diferente.

El botón y el view son del mismo color

El fondo de la pantalla es blanco.

El botón con bordes redondeados ya lo tengo, solo me falta puntualmente poder posicionar el botón como a la mitad del view, que parece que esta encimado, pero los contraits me han fallado hasta el momento.

Comment: como es el botón? es cuadrado y tiene esa forma en azul y el resto es transparente? son 2 cosas superpuestas? tendrás que poner constraints a los lados y abajo

Comment: Gracias, ya añadi mas detalles, es un botón y un view, el botón esta encima del view

Answer (score 1):

Haz que el `UIButton` sea hijo del `UIView` (no es necesario pero por comodidad), y sólo necesitas dos *constraints*:

- Centra ambos *views* en *X*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Haz que el `UIButton` esté centrado en *Y* tomando como referencia la parte de arriba del `UIView`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya que el `UIButton` tiene su propio *intrinsicContentSize*, no es necesario ponerle otros *constraints*, ya que se va a adaptar a su contenido.

Pero si el texto del botón será muy largo, recomendaría añadieras *leading* y *trailing* *constraints* entre el botón y el *view* con relación de *Greater Than Or Equal* y *Less Than Or Equal*, respectivamente. O bien, sólo un *width constraint*. Esto para evitar que el botón adopte un ancho más grande que la pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

UIView que tenga un Leading = 0 Trailing = 0 Bottom = 0 con el padre. Asígnale también un Height.

Luego añade el botón con un Height y un Width y céntralo en el eje X de la View y dale un vertical spacing a tu gusto.

Te adjunto cómo quedaría en un storyboard con sus constraints.

[image: UIView]

[image: UIButton]
Por cierto no olvides para dar curva al botón a tu gusto por código de esta manera:

```
var button = UIButton()
button.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
```